# "The specified child already has a parent" How can I remove view from AlertDialog

Tags: android

I am inflating a LinearLayout into an AlertDialog. it works fine but if I dismis it and launch it again it gives me the following error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a
>   parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

in the contructor:

```
infoWindow = (LinearLayout) ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.map_info_content, null);
```

later:

```
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
        Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        dialog.setView(infoWindow);
        dialog.show();
        return true;
    }
```

I have tried to keep the dialog  in memory and setting it's view as null but it didn't fix the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot re-use inflated views in Android once you've added them to a parent `ViewGroup`. At your side, you're trying to reuse an inflated view in your dialog. To solve this problem, inflate the view in your AlertDialog class itself.

I'd recommend you to create a separate class for it. Here's how the `onCreateDialog` method would look like:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstance){

    // create a new dialog builder
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // dialog view to inflate
    View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                                .inflate(R.layout.map_info_content, null);

    // sets the view of our dialog
    builder.setView(view);

    // create and return the dialog
    return builder.create();
}
```

Comment: Also, this is a duplicate question and this a solution to this error has been asked several times on StackOverflow. A quick search won't hurt :)